# Creating a multiline string using a for loop in python

Tags: python

I am trying to get text via the return function to concat into a multiline string such as shown below.

```
btc_positions=[{
'symbol: BTC', 
'margin_balance: 0.15',
'margin_position: 0.05',
'margin_frozen: 0.01'}]

for pos in btc_positions:
    for attributes in pos:
        text = f"{attributes}: {pos[attributes]}"
    return text
```

text is in this format (symbol: BTC) but throws the error 'return' outside function.

Console Error: python shitcoin_alerts.py
  File "shitcoin_alerts.py", line 34
    return text
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function. Fixed! (Return has to be used inside a function)

My intention is to return text to create the multiline string below. But can't seem to find any ways I can do it.

```
multiline_text = f'''
symbol={symbol},
margin_balance: {margin_balance},
margin_position:{margin_position},
margin_frozen: {margin_frozen}
'''
```

Expected output from this multiline string will be:

```
-----------------------
symbol=BTC,
margin_balance=0.15,
margin_position=0.05,
margin_available=0.01
----------------------
```

Comment: `return` is to return from a function, but you are not in one.

Comment: You are showing a `set`: `{'symbol: BTC', 'margin_balance: 0.15', 'margin_position: 0.05', 'margin_frozen: 0.01'}`. Did you want a `dict`: `{'symbol': 'BTC', 'margin_balance': '0.15', 'margin_position': '0.05', 'margin_frozen': '0.01'}`?

Comment: @tdelaney you're right. thanks for this. The function fixed it. Any idea on how to use the return text to create the multiline_text?

Comment: @tdelaney set is correct. generally the api call will send back a list of objects.

Comment: Oops, I thought you had a dict that should format `multiline_text`. I'll have to change my answer.

Comment: Thanks for showing input and output, but could you show the exact output you want from the input given? Should the output be `symbol=BTC` etc...

Comment: Are you certain of the format of `btc_positions`? Where does that come from?

Comment: @tdelaney Have added the output in. The idea that I had was to iterate through the list of dicts (not objects as you are right, this is financial data) and on each dict iterate to pull out the attributes and its values and create a multiline string (which will be the payload sent to a messaging app to inform me). Generally if I just send text, I will get multiple texts on each of the attribute and value. However, I want all the attributes and values in one single payload in a multiline format. Thanks for the help. Just picked up python a few days ago. Still struggling to get some concepts.

Comment: Those aren't dicts, they are strings. `type('symbol: BTC') == str` `type({'symbol': 'BTC'}) == dict`

Comment: Sorry, I only added the first dict. Generally what I would get back is ```btc_positions=[{
'symbol: BTC', 
'margin_balance: 0.15',
'margin_position: 0.05',
'margin_frozen: 0.01'}, {
'symbol: BTC2', 
'margin_balance: 0.15',
'margin_position: 0.05',
'margin_frozen: 0.01'}]```

Comment: @TimingLiquidity - thanks for showing the exact output. It makes verifying potential solutions much easier.

Comment: So that is a list of sets of strings.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Create and print a long string

```py
btc_positions=[{ 'symbol: BTC', 'margin_balance: 0.15', 'margin_position: 0.05', 'margin_frozen: 0.01'},
               { 'symbol: BTC2', 'margin_balance: 0.15', 'margin_position: 0.05', 'margin_frozen: 0.01'}]

def test(value):
    """
    value: list of sets of strings
    """
    for p in value:  # iterate list
        d = dict(s.split(': ') for s in p)  # turn sets of strings to dict
        d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)  # reverse sort into list of tuples
        l = '-' * 15  # dashed line
        fin = f'{l}\n'  # create string to print 
        for v in d:
            fin += '='.join(v)
            fin += '\n'
        fin += l

        print(fin)


test(btc_positions)

---------------
symbol=BTC
margin_balance=0.15
margin_position=0.05
margin_frozen=0.01
---------------
---------------
symbol=BTC2
margin_balance=0.15
margin_position=0.05
margin_frozen=0.01
---------------
```

### Print out the tuple pairs without creating a long string

- Output looks the same as first function

```py
def test(value):
    """
    value: list of sets of strings
    """
    for p in value:  # iterate list
        d = dict(s.split(': ') for s in p)  # turn set of strings to dict
        d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)  # reverse sort
        l = '-' * 15  # dashed line
        print(l)
        for k, v in d:
            print(f'{k}={v}')  # print key value pairs
        print(l)
```

### Return a string for messaging app

```py
def test(value):
    """
    value: sets of strings
    """
    d = dict(s.split(': ') for s in p)  # turn set of strings to dict
    d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)  # reverse sort
    l = '-' * 15  # dashed line
    fin = f'{l}\n'
    for v in d:
        fin += '='.join(v)
        fin += '\n'
    fin += l
    return fin

# iterate through btc_positions
for v in btc_positions:
    text = test(v)

    # send text to app
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `for` loop, but loops don't need return statements. You can `break` to exit early, `continue` to go back to the top of the loop early, or just let the loop finish. All of the variables used in the loop are available to the code outside of the loop. Contrast that to a function where variables in the function are not available to the thing that calls the function. In your case, you could use an outer list to hold each formatted string as it is created in the loop.

The strings in your `set` are easy to split into name/value pairs. They can be used to create a `dict` which can then be used to format the output strings the way you want.

```
btc_positions=[{
'symbol: BTC', 
'margin_balance: 0.15',
'margin_position: 0.05',
'margin_frozen: 0.01'}]

# turn btc_positions set into dict for print parameters
btc_position_params = [
    dict(value.split(": ") for value in position)
    for position in btc_positions]


# create new list of formatted output
multiline_text_list = []
for pos in btc_position_params:
    multiline_text_list.append('''symbol={symbol},
margin_balance={margin_balance},
margin_position={margin_position},
margin_frozen={margin_frozen}'''.format(**pos))

# show result
for pos_text in multiline_text_list:
    print("--------------------")
    print(pos_text)
print("--------------------")
```